# Prove that $g=\limsup f_n$ and $h=\liminf f_n$ are Lebesgue measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Let $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions. Prove that $g=\limsup f_n$ and $h=\liminf f_n$ are Lebesgue measurable.

*Given $f_n$ being continuous on a compact set in $\mathbb{R}$, $f_n$ are Riemann integrable, thus, Lebesgue integrable.

Note we can rewrite $g$ and $h$ as the following:
$g=\limsup f_n=\bigcap_{n\rightarrow\infty}\bigcup_{k\geq n}f_k$, where $k,n\in\mathbb{N}$. Since countable union/intersection of measurable functions are measurable by the definition of $\sigma$-algebra, $g$ therefore is Lebesgue measurable.

Similarly, $h$ is measurable.

Is the above proof correct? Thank you.

Comment: what do you mean with union/intersection of functions?

Comment: Also, you can use "\limsup" for $\limsup$. Looks better than $limsup$

Comment: countable unions or countable intersections

Comment: what does it mean $f\cup g$? it is another function?

Comment: I'm okay with unions and intersections of *sets*.  How do you intersect *functions*?

Comment: here, intersections:=minimum value at one point.

Comment: @2ndaccount And what about unions?

Comment: maximum for union

Comment: Typically for maximum or minimum you will want to write $\max$ (or $\sup$ or $\vee$) and $\min$ (or $\inf$ or $\wedge$). Set operations do work on functions if you consider $f:X\to Y$ as the subset of $X\times Y$ representing its graph, so you don't want to use unions and intersections to represent maximums and minimums as some people (like me) would assume that this is what you meant.

Comment: @johnGriffin Thank you, but besides that does it look ok?

Comment: @2ndaccount You state "countable union/intersection of measurable functions are measurable by definition of $\sigma$-algebra". This is wrong, assuming you mean countable supremum/infimum (which is what makes sense here). This does follow easily from the definition, but it isn't by definition.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying that!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First we show that $g_1:=\sup_k f_k$ and $g_2 :=\inf_k f_k$ are measurable. Note that
$$g_1^{-1}(a,\infty] = \bigcup_k f_k^{-1}(a,\infty]
\quad\text{and}\quad
g_2^{-1}[-\infty,a) = \bigcup_k f_k^{-1}[-\infty,a)
$$
are measurable. Therefore the countable supremum and infimum of measurable functions are measurable. Consequently
$$
\limsup_k f_k = \inf_k(\sup_{j\geq k}f_j)
\quad\text{and}\quad
\liminf_k f_k = \sup_k(\inf_{j\geq k}f_j)
$$
are measurable functions.

Answer (score 3):

We may define
$$ \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n := \inf_{n\ge 1} \left( \sup_{k\ge n} a_k \right). $$
The function $\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n$ is then defined pointwise by
$$ \left(\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n\right) (x)
:= \limsup_{n\to\infty} \left( f_n(x) \right)
= \inf_{n\ge 1} \left( \sup_{k\ge n} f_k(x) \right).$$
If we can show that the functions
$$ g^{\wedge}(x) := \sup_{n\ge 1} g_n(x)
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
g^{\vee}(x) := \inf_{n\ge 1} g_n(x) $$
are measurable for any sequence $(g_n)$ of measurable functions, then we are done (do you see why?).  To do this, we need only show that the preimage of $(a,\infty)$ is measurable for any $a\in\mathbb{R}$.  But
\begin{align}
(g^{\wedge})^{-1}((a,\infty))
&= \bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} (g_n)^{-1}((a,\infty)).
\end{align}
But each $g_n$ is measurable, so the union is a countable union of measurable sets, therefore measurable.  Hence $g^{\wedge}$ is measurable.  By a similar argument (replacing $(a,\infty)$ with $(\infty,a)$, for example), we can show that $g^{\vee}$ is measurable.  Now, define
$$f_n^{\wedge} := \sup_{k\ge n}f_k.$$
Each $f_n^{\wedge}$ is measurable by the above.  Then
\begin{equation}
\limsup_{n\to\infty} f_n
= \inf_{n\ge 1} \left( \sup_{k\ge n} f_n \right)
= \inf_{n\ge 1} f_{n}^{\wedge},
\end{equation}
which is the infimum of measurable functions, and therefore measurable.  The argument, *mutatis mutandis*, identical for the $\liminf$.