# Prove that if $(f_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of measurable functions, then $f=\limsup f_n$ is measurable.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

What's the difference between the following two questions:

Let $f_n:[0,1]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a sequence of continuous functions. Prove that $g=\limsup f_n$ and $h=\liminf f_n$ are Lebesgue measurable.

[Prove that $g=\limsup f_n$ and $h=\liminf f_n$ are Lebesgue measurable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2388333/prove-that-g-limsup-f-n-and-h-liminf-f-n-are-lebesgue-measurable?noredirect=1#comment4925770_2388333)

Prove that if $(f_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ is a uniformly bounded sequence of measurable functions, then $f=\limsup f_n$ is measurable.

*My question is why do I need "uniformly bounded" to prove $\limsup f_n$ is measurable?

Comment: I suspect it is to avoid having $f$ take infinite values. This assumption isn't needed if we are okay with $f$ being defined into the extended real line $[-\infty,\infty]$.

Comment: @JohnGriffin Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to make sure that $\limsup_{n\in\mathbb N}f_n$ is a real function (in the sense that it only takes real values).